# lxml error, I can't pass string with Symbol into lxml

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I'm trying to pass the string `"<p>abc</p>"` into lxml:

```
import lxml
from lxml import html

str = "<p>abc</p>"
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(str)
```

But it comes out with this error message:

```
lxml.etree.ParserError: Document is empty
```

Comment: works for me - doing a `print(lxml.html.tostring(doc))` gives `b'<p>&#128077;&#128077;abc&#128077;&#128077;</p>'` with Python 3.3.3 and lxml 3.4.4

Comment: maybe I'm missing something that need to be install

Comment: my lxml is version 3.4.1 maybe that is the problem

Comment: the [lxml changelog](http://lxml.de/3.6/changes-3.6.0.html#id6) doesn't show anything obviously related to this between 3.4.1 and 3.4.4, but if you can use a later version, it is worth trying

Comment: i have tried 3.4.4 and still the same problem....